# Joining a column with nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables (tables A and B) that look like the following:

Table A:

```
Col 1    Col 2
--------------
A        1
A        2
A        3
...
A        15
...
```

Table B:

```
Col 3    Col 4
--------------
A        a
A        b
```

I would like to write a query to join table B col 4 to table A.  Table B col 3 will match table A col 1, so I would like to join on this column.  The result I am looking for is:

Table C:

```
Col 1    Col 2    Col 4
-----------------------
A        1        a
A        2        b
A        3        null
A        4        null
....
A        15       null
....
```

I tried the following:

```
select
    tableA.col1,
    tableA.col2,
    tableB.col4
from
    tableA
inner join tableB on tableA.col1 = tableB.col3
```

But this yields the result:

```
Col 1    Col 2    Col 4
-----------------------
A        1        a
A        1        b
A        2        a
A        2        b
....
A        15       a
....
```

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH A AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) AS RN
FROM TableA
), B AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col3 ORDER BY Col4) AS RN
FROM TableB
)
SELECT A.Col1, A.Col2, B.Col4
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.Col1 = B.Col3 AND A.RN=B.RN
```

[(SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c9e1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` instead of `inner join`.

- `inner join` joins only matching rows
- `left join` and `right join` returns full left or right table with matched rows from second table or nulls
- `full join` gets all the rows from both tables.

Comment: That won't give the (odd) desired results.

Answer (score 0):

use `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT 
        tableA.col1,
        tableA.col2,
        tableB.col4
    FROM tableA
    LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.col1 = tableB.col3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not posting the right query and/or results:
(I would have expected)

```
Col 1    Col 2    Col 4
-----------------------
A        1        a
A        1        b
A        2        a
A        2        b
...
```

To achieve your desired result, however odd and unusual you will need to generate a sequence number for the Table B to join to the Col 2 in Table A.
The easiest way I can think of is using subquery.

Comment: Actually yes I believe that is the result I got (I was just writing this off the top of my head)

Comment: 1) Your query as it is could **NOT** produce the result that you posted originally.  
2) Posting a code and results "from memory" is similar to "asking a librarian for a book that you once read, which had red cover and in the end of which it was discovered that they were twins" (this is nearly a quote from T.Pratchett).  3) You should **always** copy and paste (**NOT retype**) your code and results.

Answer (score 0):

Is changing the data an option?

```
Table A:

Col 1    Col 2
--------------
A        1
A        2
A        3
...
A        15
...
Table B:

Col 2    Col 4
--------------
1        a
2        b

SELECT tableA.col1, tableA.col2, tableB.col4
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.col2 = tableB.col2
```